# Convert sqlite int table to string and then input list

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to transfer items from my LIST in c# to a TABLE in SQLite. I had no clue how to do this until someone suggested that I use parameters:

This was my initial attempt: (Of course it is wrong)

```
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

    sqlite_conn.Open();

    sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table1 (Seq integer primary key, Field integer , Description integer );";

    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i+=3)
    {
        // Lets insert something into our new table:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq, Field, Description) VALUES (list[i], list[i+1], list[i+2]);"; THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS!

        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }

    sqlite_conn.Close();
}
```

This is what a user suggested I should do ( add parameters and stuff) :

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq, Field, Description) VALUES (@p1,       @p2, @p3)";
  sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 0);  // dummy initial values 
  sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 0);
  sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i+=3)
{
   sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i]);
  ** sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i+1]); ERROR OCCURS HERE
   sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i+2]); 
   sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 }
```

***The Problem :***

Inside the for loop, as indicated by the 2 stars, I am getting an error saying: ***"Input string was not in a correct format."***

I tried to look at the solutions to previous posts which had the same error as this but not much luck so far.

I think my error is that the list initially has string values but later I try inputting into it integer sqlite columns (see create table statement in original code)

Since the original list values are all strings, how would I simply make a table insqlite which stores STRING values from my list and avoid the error?

Can someone pls help me with the exact syntax?

Comment: Pretty sure your problem is just that the index method cant do the add of i+1.  If you added those together outside the brackets you'd probably have it.

Comment: also, you might have wanted to do ++i instead of i+1.  You are incrementing your for loop by 3 each time, and could be simply incrementing i inside the loop.

Comment: tried changing list to only [i] but still no luck

Answer (score 2):

To declare a database column as a text column instead of an integer column, replace `integer` with `text`.

To set a string parameter, do not convert it into an integer; just drop the `Convert.ToInt32` call and use the value directly.

Comment: Hey, I tried your method, still no luck - I'm still getting the error "Input string was not in a correct format."
Anything on why this is happening ? @CL.